# When I select item combobox validation can changed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

When I select item from combobox, how can validation be changed in mvc project ?

Comment: can you show us some cood in order to help you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

js

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
sel.onchange = function() {
  var selected_value = this.value;
  // do your validation
}
```